# Can the iPhone be virtualized?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, virtualization

I'm currently using the iOS simulator that comes with xcode but it has limitations. I'd like to have a virtualized version of the iPhone, as close as possible to the real thing in all aspects.
Does such software exist to do this? I search but nothing came up.
Thanks,
John

Comment: http://techcrunch.com/2014/07/01/virtual-says-it-can-emulate-ios-or-android-devices-in-the-cloud/

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, Citrix has acquired that company so must have plans to launch something in the future http://techcrunch.com/2014/09/16/citrix-acquires-virtual-an-android-and-ios-virtualization-company/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the given iPhone simulator of Xcode is the only one you can use for it..or maybe the best one.
The only chance for something better would be to submit for the apple developer program and use a real device for testing.

Comment: Thanks TDogg. I'll use the xcode simulator until someone figures out how to virtualize the iphone. It would be super cool to have the various versions of iOS/Android available in the same way that we have VMs on an ESX server.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure iOS Simulator is the best simulator you could find, talking about the nearest experience to a real iOS device. If you are asking this because you are not Enrolled in the Apple Developer Program you can always use other alternatives to test in real devices (Jailbreak Tweaks and stuff like that). Or just Eroll the program.

Hope it Helps.